# The adjective "close" in a competitive situation

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/close) defines "close" thus:

> Adj
>   (With reference to a competitive situation) won or likely to be won by
>   only a small amount or distance: 
>   "the race will be a close contest"
>   "she finished a close second"

**My question:**

Based on the same sense of the word, can I describe the 'difference' or the 'differential' between two numbers or amounts of something as 'close'. For example:

> The differential between what you owe and the credit you have is
>   close.
>   The difference between their numbers of followers
>   on Twitter is close.

Does this sound nearly native? If not, what would be? I know we usually say "small difference" but I wonder if 'close' would be more effective, especially in the second sentence.

Comment: In both of your examples, "small" is much more natural than "close."

Comment: *Close* describes a relationship between two things, not the distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "close" in your examples, it might prompt a reader to respond "close to what?" as "[close](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/close)" is more idiomatic with "to" *usually* meaning a short distance away or apart in space or time.

You had better use "[narrow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/narrow)" which means:

> Limited in extent, amount, or scope:

or ***small***.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

If you Google "difference is close", many of the hits
 you find has "to" after "close".

You could hear "[The election results are too close to call](http://heightsobserver.org/read/2011/12/01/heights-election-results-are-too-close-to-call)", but here "close" is used because election is also one form of competition.